# quarkus dependency not in lib folder

Tags: quarkus

Quarkus noob question.

Quarkus version: 2.3.1.Final

After building (with `mvn package`), I can see all my projects jar files in `target/quarkus-app/lib/main`. eg. `uk.co.mycompany.my-project1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`, `uk.co.mycompany.my-project2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`, etc.

I can also see a lot of other dependencies, which I'm assuming is gathered from the projects pom files.

However, when I add a new dependency, in this case `jakarta.ws.rs-api`, I can't see it under the lib folder.

I've tried an `mvn clean package` but it just results in the same jar files as before.

How does quarkus build the list of jars? Where does it get them from?

**EDIT**

Child project pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>mycompany-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>mycompany-common</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jackson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
</project>
```

Building project pom excerpt

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.Final</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build</goal>
                        <goal>generate-code</goal>
                        <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Can you show what your `pom.xml` file looks like?

Comment: I was hoping for a quick answer to the question "How does quarkus build the list of jars" so I can try and diagnose myself. If this is not possible then which pom's/sections do you require since I have over 50?

Comment: The quick answer is that Quarkus just uses Maven to figure out which jars the user added a dependency. Adding the `pom.xml` lines for the dependency that you say isn't being added could help